# Cannot set attrs in logstash from logback

Tags: spring, logstash, logback

I am wanting to control the index my logs go to, based on the environment of my application. So for instance I have `some-app-dev`, `some-app-test`, `some-app-uat`. In my logback.xml I have an appender configured:

```
    <appender name="stash" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
        <destination>${LOGSTASHHOST}:${LOGSTASHPORT}</destination>
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
            <customFields>{"appname":"some-app-test"}</customFields>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

And then in my `pipline.conf` file I have:

```
...
output {
    elasticsearch {
        index => "%{[attrs][appname]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}
```

But when I go to Kibana, and check my indices, I see: `%{[attrs][appname]}-2020.01.20`.

So the `%{[attrs][appname]}` is not substituting correctly, and is being treated like a literal, and I have no idea why. I can't seem to send any attributes from my logger of my Spring App, to logstash it would seem.

Comment: what is `[attr][appname]` and what values does it contain?

Comment: Do you see 'some-app-test' anywhere else in the **documents**? If the value gets send to logstash correctly, the documents should contain a field with value *some-app-test*

Comment: @apt-get_install_skill No it doesn't get sent. I could just log the app name in every log, but I didn't want to do that & use attributes, I believe that is the correct way to do it, and seems to be what's recommended, I just can't get logback to play game: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/create-dynamic-index-in-elasticsearch/106579

Comment: Are you sure that the field 'appname' is under the json-element 'attrs'? The link you've posted is not directly linked to logback. I'm not sure if all the custom fields you declare in logback get under [attrs].